# git pull error: cannot lock ref 'ref/remotes/origin/xxx' ... exists; cannot create

Tags: git

I have done several git pulls today, without issue.I have not changed or modified anything locally.

Now I do another git pull, and out of the blue get this:

```
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/task/DEV-2527/DEV-2535': 'refs/remotes/origin/task/DEV-2527' exists; cannot create 'refs/remotes/origin/task/DEV-2527/DEV-2535'
From https://dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx-web/_git/xxx-web
 ! [new branch]          task/DEV-2527/DEV-2535 -> origin/task/DEV-2527/DEV-2535  (unable to update local ref)
```

I tried "git gc" but this didn't help.

I have read that "git remote prune origin" may help, but I don't want to do anything which could damage the azure remote repo.

Comment: Pruning is a local operation and will not damage anything in the remote repository.

The problem stems from the fact that you have two branches sharing a "directory-like" prefix: `task/branch_a` and `task/branch_a/branch_b`.

A solution would be to either rename or "unnest" the branch: `task/branch_b`.

Comment: Interestingly, I dont think I created this nested structure.  It must be something another dev pushed. How do we fix?

Comment: My guess is that it is already fixed in the remote repo and you only need to `git fetch --prune` to remove the leftover branch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

git fetch --prune

Fixed it for me. A developer accidentally created a new branch with a path of an old branch.  The old branch was later deleted on the origin, so presumably prune fixed this locally.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue like this and I removed folder,
'`.git/refs/remotes/origin`'
after removed, issue is solved to me

Answer (score 0):

As a datapoint, if you `git clone` this repository to a new directory do you still see the same error? This will help us understand if this problem is indeed just local and/or remote. If you can clone to a different directory I would just use the new directory.